# dc.js barchart Click unable to fadeout other bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to DC.js and crossfilter. I have a barChart and a rowChart.  Selection and filtering is working as expected. After I click the barChart , I see the filter ok but other bars are not faded out.

I want all other Bars to fadeout (except one selected), similar to the row chart.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usingh2buffaloedu/yyps72k5/27/

my data looks like below:

```
    var data = [{"Period":"Q1 2017","Group":"Group1",, more
```

jsfiddle has all the script and data.

I am using Crossfilter for all grouping. 
Any ideas? Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: There's no need to cross-post questions about dc.js and crossfilter - the same people read SO as the user group. [I answered the question over there](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/azOg_Tq_ufg/9RrkZU_HAgAJ), but in general I prefer SO.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This issue is resolved.